# Getting multi Values from a dropdown list in PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my drop down list.

```
<p align="center"><select size="1" name="bo_chose" id="boID">
<option selected value="Select...">Select...</option>

<?php
while ($list_bo = mysql_fetch_array($select_brof)) {
echo "<option value=\"$list_bo[bo_name]     $list_bo[bo_code]\">$list_bo[bo_code],$list_bo[bo_name]</option>"; }
?>

</select></p>
```

So the drop down will show first "select..."
and then will retrieve data andlist the bo_name, bo_code in `<option>`

It works well.

The problem is, I want to carry the value to another PHP page which will delete the
selected option in the drop down.
Of course the MySQL and PHP will complain that it does not exist ...why?

Its taking the new value $bo_chose  (name of the dropdown list) as a new value
as (bo_name, bo_code) — as one value not as a split values.

So if the dropdown list is (george Mike GM)
the data will complain that there is no value called "George Mike GM"
when I want it to carry only "GM" which is the bo_code.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Just split the value with space as delimiter and pick the first value. May I know why do you 
need to carry both name and id in first place.

Comment: Why I need to add both? I have at the top of the code a JavaScript wich will echo the value. and i want to echo the bo_name NOT the bo_code and the bo_code is the KEY in mySql. SO carried value should be bo_code but echoed value for user should be bo_code

Answer (score 0):

You should just add $list_bo['bo_code'] as option value instead of both.

Comment: Why I need to add both? I have at the top of the code a JavaScript wich will echo the value. and i want to echo the bo_name NOT the bo_code and the bo_code is the KEY in mySql. SO carried value should be bo_code but echoed value for user should be bo_code

Comment: in such case you can go with split as suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have this select inside a POST form or you are sending it by ajax to the script you want to parse the value. Use a separator to merge these two variables. The separator should be a char that you are sure, it will never be in either of two variables. So, you can for example use ; for the separator and write $list_bo[bo_name].';'.$list_bo[bo_code]. In the recieving script you just explode the value by separator and you will get both values as array. If you are unsure which chars will be in both variables, you can either json_encode or serialize it before puting it into html.

Comment: Im Sorry Anze, May you give me an Example please?

Comment: Firstly, do you need both, name and code in the destination php script, or do you only need an identifier (code)?

Comment: in the destination php script (which should be excuted) I need only the bo_code which is the primary key in MySql.

Comment: Okay, than really avoid using separator. Just put $list_bo[bo_code] in the value of the option.

Comment: If i put only $list_bo[bo_code] in the value..it works perfectly. the reason that I put 2 values is..the output of user choice of the drop down list will popup a javascript window and will say (Do you really want to delete $bo_name ?) and if user press Yes the script should excute bo_code....so reason why bo_name is there is just to echo it to user....sounds stupid?

Comment: Is this javascript executed in the same scope as the select or on the destination page?

Comment: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> function confirmAction() { var boChoice = document.getElementById("boID"); if(document.del_bo.bo_chose.value=="Select...") { alert('Please choose a name ...'); return false; } return confirm("Do you want to delete " + boChoice.value + "? " ) } </SCRIPT>

Comment: Its in the same page...see boID is the output of the dropdown box..which shows bo_code and bo_name like Anze Jarni AJ but i want to carry from the drop down only AJ

Comment: Okay! Put bo_code in value and bo_name in data-name property. You can than fetch the name from JS with boChoice.getAttribute('data-name')

Comment: Thank you very much Anze for your time and help, I really appreciate it. my best regards.